# How do I add a frame to a batch of images using photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, batch-processing

I know how to add a frame to a single photo in Photoshop, but I don't know an easy way to choose multiple photos and apply the same type of frame to all of them. Can anyone suggest a method please?

Answer (score 4):

Use the "Batch" utility in PS.  Look under File>Automate>Batch (Mac).  From here you choose the Action, files, etc. You can create and save an Action that includes your choose Frame and edits via the Action Panel (Window>Actions).

Comment: Better yet, use the batch function in Bridge (Tools > Photoshop > Batch).

Answer (score 0):

You can use frame fun application.Its free,easy to download and use.You can add frame to multiple pics in one go.

Comment: Can you please explain how to use it? And why not using Photoshop? That was asked in the question ...  BTW: Welcome to GD.SE!